# Using Text Files in c++

Tags: c++, text-files

I have to make a quiz program (like *Who wants to be a millionaire?*), inputting questions as a user from a text file. This is what I wrote so far. It's more of a tester for a preview. If I add a return main at the end of the last condition for storing questions (which is at `k.close();`), I cannot reenter from the beginning. What am I doing wrong? And is this a positive way to continue my program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

   ofstream k;
   ifstream r;
   string f,a,b,c,d,e;


   int a;
   cout<<"1) Luaj"<<endl;
   cout<<"2) Dil nga programi"<<endl;
   cout<<"Zgjedhja juaj: ";
   cin>>a;
   if(a==1){
      cout<<"Ti je :"<<endl;
      cout<<"1)Administrator"<<endl;
      cout<<"2) Lojtar"<<endl;
      cout<<"Zgjedhja juaj: ";
      cin>>a;
      if(a==1){
         cout<<"1) Vendos pyetjet"<<endl;
         cout<<"2) Kthehu ne menune kryesore"<<endl;
         cout<<"Zgjedhja juaj: ";
         cin>>a;
         if(a==1){

            cout<<"Vendosni pyetjen: ";
            getline(cin,a);
            cout<<"Vendonsi alternativen 1";
            cin>>b;
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 2: ";
            cin>>c;
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 3: ";
            cin>>d;
            cout<<"Vendosni alternativen 4: ";
            cin>>e;
            cout<<"Vendosni pergjigjen: ";
            cin>>f;


            k.open("t.txt");
            k<<a<<endl;
            k<<b<<endl;
            k<<c<<endl;
            k<<d<<endl;
            k<<e<<endl;
            k.close();


         }

      }else{
         cout<<"1) Luaj"<<endl;
         cout<<"2) Kthehu ne menune kryesore"<<endl;
         cin>>a;
         if(a==1){

            string s;
            r.open("t.txt");
            cout<<"Pyetja 1: ";
            if(r.is_open()){
               while(getline(r,s)){
                  cout<<s<<endl;
               }
            }
            r.close();
            string pergj;
            cout<<"Vendosni pergjigje: ";
            cin>>pergj;
            if(pergj==f){
               cout<<"true";
            }
         }

      }

   }else   {
      return 0;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is.  Please clarify the issue.

Comment: use goto? loops? delegates/timers?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'd like to make a millionare program where i can store my own questions and then play with them...like the program should have two characters . one administrator which inputs the questions, and the player which plays

Comment: What is a "millionare program"?

Comment: @Abra im not following you

Comment: @melpomene who is going to be a millionare

Comment: You mean "Who wants to be a millionaire?", as in the quiz show?

Comment: @melpomene yes thats right

Comment: Create a struct 'Question'. Store everything you need as members. Overload operator<< and operator>>. Then create some kind of menu mechanism that stores menu options and callbacks and loops over the options over and over.

Answer (score 2):

> i cannot reenter from the beginning. What am i doing wrong?

You need a loop.

```
while ( some_condition_is_true )
{
   // The main logic
}
```

For example, you can refactor `main` to:

```
bool coreFunction();

int main()
{
   while ( coreFuntion() )
   {
   }
}
```

and move all of the code from `main` to `coreFunction` while adding the necessary logic to decide when to stop the program.

```
bool coreFunction()
{
   // Variable to note whether to continue the program or not.
   bool cont = true;

   // Figure out when to continue or not.
   // Set the value of cont accordingly.

   // ...
   // Your current code.
   // ...

   return cont;
}
```

Comment: But am i storing the questions well in the text file. can i access them them in the fstream object i made?

Comment: @SalvadoreRina, unfortunately I don'n understand what your program does. You will have to figure out those details without my help.

Comment: Thank you anyways for your help

Comment: Yes! >>function<< is a good keyword here... That main() is scary long.

Comment: @smoothware, agree. People don't always think of programs, even small programs, in terms of functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add lots of new questions into your "Who Wants to be a Millionaire" game from a text file, I would suggest that you create some sort of structure or class that would contain each question along with the four possible answers and also what the correct answer is. For example something like:

```
struct millionaire
{
    std::string question; ///< The question to ask user
    std::string a;        ///< choice A
    std::string b;        ///< choice B
    std::string c;        ///< choice C
    std::string d;        ///< choice D
    int answer;           ///< The correct answer 1=A, 2=B etc.
};
```

Then you could have a standard input file format where the first line of text is the question, the second line is choice A, etc. and the pattern repeats for each question in the file for example:

#### questions.txt

Which character was first played by Arnold Schwarzenegger in a 1984 film?
The Demonstrator
The Instigator
The Investigator
The Terminator
4
Which color is used as a term to describe an illegal market in rare goods?
Blue
Red
Black
White
3
...

You could then write a simple loop to consume your questions.txt file and store it into a vector of your structures to be used during the game like this for example:

```
std::vector<millionaire> gameQuestions;
std::ifstream inputfile("questions.txt");

if (inputfile.is_open())
{
    millionaire temp;
    while (std::getline(inputfile, temp.question))
    {
        std::getline(inputfile, temp.a);
        std::getline(inputfile, temp.b);
        std::getline(inputfile, temp.c);
        std::getline(inputfile, temp.d);
        std::getline(inputfile, temp.answer);

        gameQuestions.push_back(temp);
    }
    inputfile.close();
}
```

An approach along these lines should help you better organize and structure your data so that you don't end up with a giant mess of conditionals etc.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really help you, but I can suggest you to use comment like this way. I guess you are novice in programing, like I was there is no long time.
SO here is my advice :
You want to do something, create a commentary of what you want to do from the start:

```
// Choose a mode between Play, ??? or quit ? (Here is the place of the loop
//Play
    // Choose between admin or player
        // Administrator
            // Create some question
            // Modify answer
            // Go back to menu



        // Player
        // Choose a level
// ???
    // Action

// Quit
    //End of the program
```

Then you make your code under your comments like that you can easier do it. If it is not, don't hesitate to go further with the comments, and then this should help to receive some answers.
Also if you don't want your program to stop, you have to use a loop (while /do while condition0) to enclose the code to repeat.
But remember this, the comments are really important in the program, this is the basis. So take time to write or draw what you want to do, as easier it can be, then the programming will flow by itself.
Hopes it can help you.
Think also to say hello and please. ;-)